# Swift UI Overlay a list to a background color

Tags: swift, list, uitableview, swiftui, swiftui-list

I just want to set a Color as background color to my list. Can't find anything that work,

It looks like is not possible, I don't want to change every single color of my row.

Any tips how to do it? Looks like `SwiftUI` and `List` don't allow the background color, it allow only color per single raw.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.orange, .red]), center: .center, startRadius: 100, endRadius: 470).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    List(0 ..< 5) { item in
                        Text("Test")
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add

```swift
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear 
}
```

to your struct and then set background for your list.