# Background Image of Navigation View with List View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to set the image as the background of the list, so I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60150487/navigation-view-background-color) as a reference and ran with it.
(I used Image instead of gradient)

Here's my code

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestContentView: View {

    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear// Uses UIColor
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Image("milkyway")
            .resizable()
            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

            .overlay(List {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { index in
                    NavigationLink( destination: DetailView()) {
                        ContentCell()
                    }
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    .listRowBackground(Color.clear) // Uses Color
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My List"))

        }
    }
}

struct ContentCell: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Text("An item to display.")
            }
            .frame(width: (geometry.size.width), height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.clear)// Working
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text ("At the detail view")
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.clear)// Working
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct TestContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestContentView()
    }
}
```

It seemed to work fine.
However, as you can see from [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNCge.png), the content overlaps with largeTitle.
EDIT:(If you scroll that screen, largeTitle and contents will overlap.)

How can it work?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
struct WelcomeScene: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            splashImageBackground
                .overlay(
                    VStack {
                        Text("Content here")
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                )
        }
    }

    private var splashImageBackground: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Image("OnboardingSplash")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should [edit] your answer to include an explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context to those who might come across the same issue later on.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71251214/10830091):

If need to use `NavigationView`, and maintain the image's aspect ratio, you can do this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct FullScreenPictureDemo: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Image("your_full_screen_background_picture")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .scaledToFill()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```